# TypeError: $ is not a function Error using parallax effect in Wordpress Template

Tags: jquery, javascript, page-template

I`m trying to include a parallax Effect into one of my cutsom page templates. The js function is returning the following error in the firebug console:

**TypeError: $ is not a function**

The error is on the first line wich is:

**var parallaxElements = $('.parallax'),**

Any help would be appreciated. Here the full code:

```
    var parallaxElements = $('.parallax'),
        parallaxQuantity = parallaxElements.length;

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < parallaxQuantity; i++) {
        var currentElement =  parallaxElements.eq(i);
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        currentElement.css({
        'transform': 'translate3d(0,' + scrolled * -0.3 + 'px, 0)'
        });

    }
});

});
```

Comment: What happens if you change `$` to `jQuery` ? [jQuery is included in compatibility mode by default](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I changed all the $ to jQuery and the errors are gone - but the effect dont work? http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/mPpZZM/

Comment: Looks like the codepen works for me - the background moves as you scroll.

Comment: The codepen works fine - but not in my template... can´t figure it out :(

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery instead of $.
e.g use jQuery('.parallax') instead of $('.parallax').

Comment: I changed all the $ to jQuery and the errors are gone - but the effect dont work? codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/mPpZZM